# Networking with Java, how to check if a HTTP request is a directory?

Tags: java, networking

I'm making a web server using java for a project and I'm having particular trouble with a certain task.

I need to check if the requested resource is a directory. If it is, it needs to check there is a file in the directory called "index.html" but I'm having trouble knowing when a directory is the resource?

Comment: Are you really sure that you are trying make a web server? Seems like you are trying to mix the request URL and the file system.

Comment: Can you post some code ? What have you tried ? What about `(new File("/path/to/dir")).isDirectory()` ?

Comment: Why? Just deploy Tomcat and use the default servlet. It will figure all that out.